# Header with gradient image overlay

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to add a header with a gradient image overlay to an app I am making.
The below code has been trimmed down and simplified in the hope to make it meaningful to you.

The header should be visible on all screens, where some screens show the back button and only the front screen show a logo and settings to the right.

How can I solve that?

```
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Example from '../components/example';

const navContainer = (Comp, options) => {
  return StackNavigator({
    Main: {
      screen: Comp,
      navigationOptions: options
    },
    S1: {
      screen: Example
    },
    S2: {
      screen: Example,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
          headerTitle: <Example {...navigation.state.params} />,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'white'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    S3: {
      screen: Example,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
          headerTitle: <Example {...navigation.state.params} />,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'white'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    S4: {
      screen: Example,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
          headerTitle: <Example {...navigation.state.params} />,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'white'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    }
  })
}

const navOptions = title => {
  return {
    headerTitle: title,
    headerBackTitle: null,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }
  }
}

const NavTab = TabNavigator(
  {
    M1: {
      screen: navContainer(Example, navigation => ({
        headerTitle: <Example />,
        headerRight: <Example { ...navigation } />,
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        }
      }))
    },
    M2: {
      screen: navContainer(Example, navOptions('M2'))
    },
    M3: {
      screen: navContainer(Example, navOptions('M3'))
    },
    M4: {
      screen: navContainer(Example, navOptions('M4'))
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    lazy: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      inactiveBackgroundColor: 'white',
      activeBackgroundColor: 'white'
    }
  }
);

export default NavTab;
```

The example component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Example extends Component {

  static style = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
    }
  })

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={ Example.style.container }>
        <Text>hello</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first attempt was to overwrite [Header._renderHeader](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/src/views/Header.js), but the status bar was still not covered. 
The final solution is below the `<hr />`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Header } from 'react-navigation';
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar, Image } from 'react-native';

import img_gradient from '../images/headerbg.png';

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  img: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'stretch'
  }
});

export default class NavHeader extends Header {

  _renderHeader (props) {
    const left = this._renderLeft(props);
    const right = this._renderRight(props);
    const title = this._renderTitle(props, {
      hasLeftComponent: left !== null,
      hasRightComponent: right !== null
    });
    return (
      <View key={ `scene_${ props.scene.key }` } style={ [StyleSheet.absoluteFill, style.header] }>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        <Image source={ img_gradient } style={ style.img }>
          { title }
          { left }
          { right }
        </Image>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

---

Here's how I solved it, by putting my root element inside BgImg: `<BgImg><App /></BgImg>`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

import img_gradient from '../images/headerbg.png';

export default class BgImg extends Component {

  static style = StyleSheet.create({
    img: {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      resizeMode: 'stretch'
    }
  })

  render () {
    return (
      <Image source={ img_gradient } style={ BgImg.style.img }>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        { this.props.children }
      </Image>
    );
  }

}
```